# Discord Bot Error

Tags: python, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import asyncio

bot = commands.Bot(commabds_prefix='#')

@bot_event
async def on_ready():
    print ("Ready when you are")
    print ("I am running on" + bot.user.name)
    print ("With the ID: " + bot.user.id)

bot.run("Token")
```

I'm using Python to create a discord bot and when I use this code I get this error through command prompt:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\reals\Desktop\Discord Bot\bot.py", line 3, in <module>
    import discord
  File "C:\Users\reals\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .client import Client, AppInfo, ChannelPermissions
  File "C:\Users\reals\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 38, in <module>
    from .state import ConnectionState
  File "C:\Users\reals\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\state.py", line 36, in <module>
    from . import utils, compat
  File "C:\Users\reals\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\compat.py", line 32
    create_task = asyncio.async
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Your `@bot_event` decorator is never imported, so the interpreter does not know what it is.

Comment: It `@bot.event`, with a dot, not an underscore. Voting to close as typo. And your actual error is because discord.py doesn't officially support Py 3.7, use the developmental version from github or run Python <3.7. Search the [discord.py] tag, there's already multiple questions discussing that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already importing commands from discord.ext, you dont need to import Bot as far as i can see. Because you are not using it.

Other than that, your `bot = commands.Bot(commabds_prefix='#')` is miss typed.

It is `commands_prefix`, not `commabds`, so change it and you should be able to go.

Comment: Also i just saw that you are using ``@bot_event`` too but that should be ``@bot.event``

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import asyncio

bot = commands.Bot(commabds_prefix='#')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print ("Ready when you are")
    print ("I am running on" + bot.user.name)
    print ("With the ID: " + bot.user.id)

bot.run("Token")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the import statement at line 3 is causing the issue, also it is not required.

**Can you remove line 3 and try again?**

Note that you are using *command.Bot()*, *command* being imported at line 2.

Comment: This won't work.  `discord.ext.commands.Bot` is a subclass of `discord.Client`, so `discord` is going to be imported as a dependency anyways.